# Swift method overloading inference not working

Tags: swift, generics, overloading, codable

I'm trying to create a generic JSON mapper for my application. I'm using the Codable protocol and I have two functions: one to convert data to decodable and one to convert encodable to data. Here's my implementation:

```
struct JSONMapper: JSONMapperProtocol {
    func map<T: Encodable>(from entity: T) -> Data? {
        let encoder = JSONEncoder()
        guard let data = try? encoder.encode(entity) else {
            return nil
        }

        return data
    }

    func map<T: Decodable>(from data: Data) -> T? {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        guard let entity = try? decoder.decode(T.self, from: data) else {
            return nil
        }

        return entity
    }
}
```

My desirable usage of these functions is this:

```
if let body = requestData.body {
    request.httpBody = self.mapper.map(from: body)
}
```

requestData is an implementation of this protocol:

```
protocol RequestData {
    var method: HTTPMethod { get }
    var host: String { get }
    var path: String { get }
    var header: [String: String]? { get }
    var queryParameters: [String: String]? { get }
    var body: Encodable? { get }
}
```

But the compiler gives me the following error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'Encodable' to expected argument type 'Data'

I don't get why this is happening because 'httpBody' is a Data and 'body' is a Encodable. Should't the compiler be able to infer this?

I appreciate any thoughts to solve this issue.

**Configuration:**

Compiler: Swift 4.2

Xcode: 10.1

Comment: Can you add code of some struct/class connected with `requestData.body`?

Comment: Request Data is actually a protocol. I'll add the protocol in the question.

Comment: `body` must be a concrete type, not the protocol `Encodable`.

Comment: Why I can't use it this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method's expecting concrete type (`T`), which implements protocol `Encodable` (`<T: Encodable>`).

So you can't use it this way, because `body` has to be a concrete type since `Encodable` is just protocol for struct/class which should implement it. You have to specify what is the type which implements this protocol.

---

To achieve this, you can declare `associatedtype` which has to implement `Encodable` protocol and then you can specify type of `body` as this associated type

```
protocol RequestData {
    ...
    associatedtype T: Encodable
    var body: T? { get }
}
```

then inside of the struct/class which implements your protocol you have to specify type of `T` as concrete type of struct/class which implements protocol `Encodable`

```
struct SomeStruct: RequestData {
    ...
    typealias T = SomeOtherStruct
    var body: T?
}
```

then compiler doesn't give you any error and it should work:

```
request.httpBody = self.mapper.map(from: body)
```

Comment: This works. If I understand correctly, the problem is that my function was expecting a generic encodable while I was using a concrete type. If you agree, could you add this to your answer?

Comment: @GabrielGomes your function's expecting concrete type which implements protocol `Encodable`

Answer (score 0):

For decoding see below, for encoding just change JSONDecoder() to JSONEncoder()

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
if let data = response.data {
   do {
      let userList = try decoder.decode(UserList.self, from: data)
   }
   catch {
      print(error)
   }
}
```

Use this to decode the response data, you can use a struct or a class then with Codable as a type.

```
struct UserList: Codable {
   var responseCode: String
   var response: UserListResponse
}
```

Which can like the above have layers of codable types.

Comment: This is not answering my question. My coding/decoding logic is working, I just want to know why the compiler can't infer which of the functions I'm calling.

Comment: does it work if you change from to fromData, and the other to fromType? just curious if it infers it then

Comment: I just tried this, still not woking. But now the error is "Incorrect argument label in call (have 'fromEntity:', expected 'fromData:')"